# Digitally Sign a Click Once Application

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, pfx

I am working in the End User Computing Team in a locked down Enterprise environment.  We have a requirement to digitally sign all ClickOnce applications, so when downloaded and run, the application will work in the locked down environment without being blocked.

The relevant team has created an in-house digitally signed certificate (we have the .pfx file), but the business do not want to give the certificate to the team/developer who authored the ClickOnce application.

Ordinarily the developer of the ClickOnce application would open the project in Visual Studio and attach the .pfx file within the "Sign Manifests" tab and then publish the "ClickOnce" to the webserver.  The user would  then be able to download and run the ClickOnce all signed.

Is there a way do sign the ClickOnce application without providing the developer with the certificate?  The developer could provide the VS Project etc but this is not really an option.

Somehow we need to digitally sign each ClickOnce application from the EUC end, maybe after the ClickOnce has been published?

Any ideas or thoughts welcome.

Is mage.exe an option to maybe point to the webserver location where the click once resides?  This would be controlled by the EUC side, so developer would have no exposure to the certifcate?

Thanks

If you simply sign the executable without publishing this will not work as the application has to be signed during a publish or maybe after?